# ListView Click in android fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I can't move from `fragment` to `Activity` on ListItem Click Listener i think i am doing it right but don't know where is problem.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.scholorship_listing_main,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {


    super.onStart();


    list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Scholorshiplist);
    setAdapterValue();


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

    {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScholorshipDetail.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            //getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

}
```

And my `Activity` class on which I want to move is

```
public class ScholorshipDetail extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scholorship_detail);
    }
}
```

and my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.temp.scholorshipapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scholorships"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/txt_scholorship"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_scholorship"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@id/txt_scholorship"
    android:id="@+id/Scholorshiplist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"

    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ca you post your onCreateView()

Comment: what is not working? what is a problem?

Comment: intent in listview click is not working @VladMatvienko

Comment: how exactly is it now working? crushing? ScholorshipDetail activity not starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be your adapter layout contains the click listener view.i.e, button view or some other view, which will block the listview click listner. So in your adapter parent layout you need add block descendent or focusability as below,

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
(OR)
android:focusable="false"
```

Hope this is helpful:)

Answer (score 2):

Post the code in onCreateview() instead of onStart() in your fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
   list=(ListView)    view.findViewById(R.id.Scholorshiplist);
   setAdapterValue();

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
 { 
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScholorshipDetail.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        //getActivity().finish();
    }
});
return view;
 }
```